# AutoHotKey replace dollar sign with percent

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to use Auto Hot Key to replace $ with %. I also am replacing & with $.

My problem is that when I press the & key (now remapped to $), it thinks I'm actually pressing $, so it triggers the code and types %.

This is the code:

```
~::@
@::?
%::^
^::~
$::Sendraw `%
&::$

?::+
/::_

+::&
=::/

_::=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My keyboard layout doesn't have these keys as actual keys, so I can't really test this for you, but I can still tell you what will likely fix the problem, and then an other version which will *definitely* fix the problem.

So the thing that will likely fix the problem is using the `$` modifier <sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#prefixdollar)</sup>. You should only need it for the `` $::Sendraw `% `` hotkey, because the other hotkeys use the [remapping syntax](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm#Remap) and will automatically do what adding the `$` does.

So your script would look like this:

```
~::@
@::?
%::^
^::~
$$::SendInput, `%
&::$

?::+
/::_

+::&
=::/

_::=
```

(and I also switched to using [`SendInput`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail) because `SendRaw` really made no sense there)

That should work if all the hotkeys are as actual keys on your keyboard layout (as opposed to being accessible with modifier key combos (e.g. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>), like they are on my keyboard layout).
Why it wouldn't work when having to mess with modifiers keys is a bit more complicated. I can explain it in detail if you're actually interested, but for now I'll just say it's because of the [blind send mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Blind) the remapping syntax uses.

So, not using the remapping syntax like this should ensure it'll work on *any* keyboard layout no matter what:

```
*~::SendInput, @
*@::SendInput, ?
*%::SendInput, {^}
*^::SendInput, ~
*$::SendInput, `%
*&::SendInput, $

*?::SendInput, {+}
*/::SendInput, _

*+::SendInput, &
*=::SendInput, /

*_::SendInput, =
```

Here we're using the `*` <sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#wildcard)</sup> modifier to deal with having to hold modifier keys to access hotkeys. And we're not using `$` modifier, because using `*` already does what `$` does. So having them both would be redundant.

Comment: Thank you, this worked.

I have another question (should I make a new post?). My AHK script doesn't work properly inside WSL. Would you know why? The keys on the right side of my keyboard don't remap properly (e.g. instead of tying / it types z)

Answer (score 0):

```
+4::SendInput, `%
```

This should work fine.